# Separating email addresses in one text file and writing to another text file

Tags: python, email, python-2.7, text, file-io

I have a text file containing several email addresses and I want to convert the block of text into a list of email addresses, with each address on a new line.

So far I am stuck because for some reason it will not write to a new file and instead I'm getting the following error:

```
traceback (most recent call last): 
    file "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> 
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

The code I have started is:

```
sTxt = open('sAck.txt', 'r')
wTxt = open('nAck.txt', 'w')

s = str(sTxt)
s.read().split(';')
wTxt.write(s) 

sTxt.close()
wTxt.close()
```

Comment: Where in that code do you think you're attempting to *"write to a new file"*?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Oh geez, I forgot to add that in, but I still always get an error when I place it directly after the split method like so: wTxt.write(s)

Comment: Please include the error you're getting, just _an error_ is very ambiguous.

Comment: @Nit the error is traceback (most recent call last):
file "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: expected a character buffer object

Comment: For future reference it's best to edit all the relevant information into your question, that way possible helpers don't have to go through comments.

Comment: @jadedartemis `s` is a `list` at that point, *not* a `str`

Comment: @Nit I will keep that in mind, this is the 1st time I've posted here and I am fairly new to python. I have used Lua a lot in the past and they appeared to be similar... however I am clearly wrong about that.

Comment: @jonrsharpe you are correct. as Nit pointed out I should have explained my question a bit better. I was kind of at wits end when I posted this and will ensure I include all of the details before I post. Prior to using the str method, I was completely omitting that part and still ended up with the same error, so I assumed that it was because the block of text wasn't converted to a string. Lua does wonky stuff like that. I do appreciate the help though. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use something like:

```
sTxt = open('sAck.txt', 'r')
wTxt = open('nAck.txt', 'w')

emails = sTxt.read().split(';')
wTxt.write('\n'.join(emails))

sTxt.close()
wTxt.close()
```

Comment: No problem, you can mark the answer as accepted using the _tick_ icon on the left side.